# Can‘t setup an iPad or Apple TV as Home Hub

Tags: ipad, appletv, homekit

I tried a lot of different things and running out of ideas. I wanted to start using the HomeKit and failed to setup a Home Hub, both with my Apple TV 4 and with my iPad. My Apple ID is setup with Two-Factor-Authentication and Keychain enabled. Home is switch on my iPhone and iPad. I also rebooted the devices several times and signed off and on e.g. in the Apple TV. I use latest OS versions. HomeKit does not show up in Apple TV and if I set to use the iPad a Home Hub, nothing changes.

All Home applications on iPad, iPhone or Mac indicated that remote access is not set up and suggest to setup a home hub.

Anything you see that I missed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are you using the same Apple ID on all the devices?  Are they all on the same network?

Comment: Yes, I use the same Apple ID on all devices, but a different one for iTunes / App store. This setup with the different ID for iTunes is the same on all devices though. The devices are on the same network, but iPhone & iPad on Wifi and the Apple TV is connected with ethernet.

Comment: I don't know if it matters but every Apple Support article I've read said to use the same Apple ID on everything (wired and wireless shouldn't matter, that's how my home is setup).  You might need to contact Apple on this one, I can't see anything you're doing that I would change.

Comment: OK, many thanks. I will contact the Apple Support on this issue and post the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same Apple ID.

Make sure you follow all the steps in [this article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207057)

> 1. Set up two-factor authentication for your Apple ID. On your iOS device, go to Settings > [your name] > iCloud and make sure that
>      iCloud Keychain is turned on.
> 2. On your Apple TV, go to Settings > Accounts and make sure that you're signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID as your iOS device.
> 3. After you sign in to iCloud, your Apple TV automatically sets itself up as a home hub.   To see if your Apple TV is connected as a
>      home hub, go to Settings on your Apple TV. Then go to Accounts >
>      iCloud and look under HomeKit.

Comment: Hi Daniil, I followed the steps above, but it does not resolve my problem. I‘ll contact Apple Support, as the only remaining hint is the use two different Apple ID‘s, but this is a very common setup and should not be the root cause. Many thanks for your support, Roland

Comment: @Roland no problem.